# Refresh python file linked to nodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

I linked a nodeJS file with a Python file in an express app. My python file generates a unique URL. However, I have to restart my server every time I want to make another test with that URL, because when I refresh my page, the Python file doesn't get refreshed. Is it normal? Can I do something to have my python file refreshed every time I refresh my page?

here is my nodeJS code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var process = spawn('python',["public/python/my_script.py"]);

var url = "";
process.stdout.on('data', function (data){
   url += data.toString();
});

/* GET home page. */
process.stdout.on('end', function(){
   console.log("URL générée !");
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     res.render('index', {
       auth_url: url
     });
   });
});

module.exports = router;`
```

Thank you, guys ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works with that code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var spawnSync = require("child_process").spawnSync;

/* Gets a new url every time it's called */
function get_url() {
   var process = spawnSync('python', ["public/python/my_script.py"]);
   return process.stdout.toString().trim();
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   var url  = get_url();
   res.render('index', {
      auth_url: url //Now call the function
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when your Node.js server loads up: It gets the result of `my_script.py` then sets the resulting value as `url`, this result is never refreshed. You will want to move your code for getting a url into function. I have also moved from [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to [`spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) because you want to wait for the results of the Python script.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var spawnSync = require("child_process").spawnSync;

/* Gets a new url every time it's called */
function get_url() {
    var process = spawnSync('python', ["public/python/my_script.py"]);
    return process.stdout.toString().trim();
}

/* GET home page. */
process.stdout.on('end', function(){
   console.log("URL générée !");
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     res.render('index', {
       auth_url: get_url() //Now call the function
     });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I understand your answer, it looks good but it doesn't work. NodeJS doesn't go through the function. I tried to put some `console.log` in the function to check.

Comment: I have tried the Sync too but it doesn't work either... I don't understand why.

Comment: Thanks ! the stdout "end" had to be removed and it works ;)